What is the idiomatic way to operate on a single Series within a DataFrame in rust polars?
I am a beginner and want to understand if my code is idiomatic polars rust.
I have written the following function:
fn transform_str_to_tb(s: Series) -> Series {
    s.iter()
        .map(|v| {
            let value = v.to_string().replace([',', '\"'], "");
            let mut parts = value.split_whitespace();
            let num = parts.next().unwrap().parse::<f64>().unwrap();
            let unit = parts.next().unwrap();

            match unit {
                "KB" => num / (1000.0 * 1000.0 * 1000.0),
                "MB" => num / (1000.0 * 1000.0),
                "GB" => num / 1000.0,
                "TB" => num,
                "PB" => num * 1000.0,
                _ => panic!("Unsupported unit: {}", unit),
            }
        })
        .collect()
}

I then call it when operating on a DataFrame as follows:
let df = df
    .lazy()
    .with_columns([col("value")
        .map(
            |s| Ok(Some(transform_str_to_tb(s))),
            GetOutput::default(),
        )
        .alias("value_tb")])
    .collect()?;

Any recommendations for how this can be improved?

You definitely don't want to use Series::iter, which produces items as AnyValue (and which you're converting to String by using the Display impl). You instead want something like this:
fn transform_str_to_tb(s: Series) -> PolarsResult<Option<Series>> {
    Ok(Some(
        s.str()?  // fallibly get underlying StringChunked
            .iter()
            .map(|x| {
                let mut parts = x?.split_whitespace();
                let num = parts.next()?.parse::<f64>().unwrap();
                let unit = parts.next()?;
                let multiplier = match unit {
                    "KB" => 1.0 / (1000.0 * 1000.0 * 1000.0),
                    "MB" => 1.0 / (1000.0 * 1000.0),
                    "GB" => 1.0 / 1000.0,
                    "TB" => 1.0,
                    "PB" => 1.0 * 1000.0,
                    _ => panic!("Unsupported unit: {}", unit),
                };

                Some(num * multiplier)
            })
            .collect::<Float64Chunked>()
            .into_series(),
    ))
}

let df = df! [
    "value" => ["1 KB", "2 TB"]
]?
.lazy()
.with_column(
    col("value").map(transform_str_to_tb, GetOutput::float_type()),
);

